# Is there a concept already for $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)/x}$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, terminology, economics

Given a differentiable real function $y=f(x)$, is there a math concept/terminology already defined for $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)/x}?$$

This quantity is inspired from  [price elasticity of demand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_elasticity_of_demand#Definition).

Thanks.

Comment: We don't name eveything, despite appearances... :-P

Comment: I don't know that this quantity itself has a name, but we can rewrite it as $x \frac{d}{dx} \log f(x)$, and $\frac{d}{dx} \log f(x)$ is itself called the *logarithmic derivative* of $f$.

Comment: ...and we can also write it more compactly as $\frac{d\log f(x)}{d\log x}$.

Answer (score 4):

Google [Books](http://books.google.com/?q=%22dimensionless%20logarithmic%20derivative%22) and [Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22dimensionless+logarithmic+derivative%22) attest that this is sometimes called the *dimensionless logarithmic derivative* of $f$, as it is a [dimensionless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_quantity) version of the better-known [logarithmic derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative).

Comment: So in price elasticity of demand, $x = P$? eg $x= P, \ f(x) = 3x \ \to \ f(P) = 3P$ so dim log derivative of f is $\frac{3}{3P/P} = 1$